# How to add admin approval for new register user in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want the functionality that any one can register in my wordpress site. After register admin get a email. Then he can approve or delete the user. If admin approve the user, then the user can login otherwise the user can not login. Can I do it without using any plugin or should I use a plugin for it? Can you also suggest which plugin is best for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no small code spinets' solution. You should use plguins. This is a useful plugins for this issue: http://wordpress.org/plugins/new-user-approve/

Comment: Yes it is useful. But I can not delete the user using this.

Comment: Wordpress has it's own options. Go to Users in the admin panel

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of password protected plugins available in wp market you can find [here...](http://www.cozmoslabs.com/13357-wordpress-user-registration-plugin/)